# Programmable microcontroller in Assembly language with breadboard

Tags: assembly, x86, raspberry-pi

I am looking for a microcontroller product like/or if possible a Raspberry-PI that will allow me to program in Assembly Language. This is for a extra credit school project but needs to be specifically programmed in assembly with some hardware like (Logic gates, I/O, etc). If I got the RPi route, is there a program, (that works with the I/O on the board) that will do this? Or other suggestions on what I can do?

I don't want to drop $100+ on a [kit](http://a.co/d/cHYRGoW) ([RPi](http://a.co/d/8cEqGYD)) that doesn't fit my needs.

Arduino's aren't the best option either.

Comment: you dont program logic gates in assembly language

Comment: a raspberry pi can be had for $5 to $10

Comment: there is a long list of microcontrollers that can be had for $2 to $20

Comment: all of the above can be programmed in assembly language, not the gates of course, but programs that run on the processor.

Comment: you dont go get an rpi program you write the rpi program.

Comment: no reason why you cant use an arduino either other than the inflated price, you can get other avr boards for less, would recommend something other than an avr for learning assembly msp430 or cortex-m based first then look at the list of others avr, mips, 8051, full sized arm, and others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by logic gates you mean hardware logic gate integrated circuits, a Raspberry Pi will allow you to do this, so will an Arduino, or a PICAX microcontroller, or a Zilog Z80 microprocessor. The options really are endless, all MCUs/MPUs use assembly to one extent or another. I would suggest either the Arduino or Raspberry Pi. Whole books are written for programming assembly specifically on the Raspberry pi. (Haven't seen any for arduino, but I'm sure they're out there.) So finding out how to program in assembly on them shouldn't be too hard at all.

You don't need to buy a $100 raspberry pi kit. Just buy the raspberry pi, figure out what other hardware you need, and buy it separately. Just be sure you have a keyboard, HDMI chord and a monitor if you buy the raspberry pi so you can program on it just like you would on a computer. I'm sure you can also program it via SSH, but this may be very difficult to set up. (I could be wrong, I haven't used a raspberry pi in many years.)

If you go for the Arduino, be sure you also get a USB chord of the proper type to program it.

A note, your answer tags "x86". Be forewarned: The Raspberry Pi does not use x86, it uses the ARM architecture. The Arduino uses AVR architecture, and the PICAX also uses its own architecture. So you won't be able to program on any of these in x86 assembly.

### What about x86 then?

The Zilog Z80 was originally designed as an extension for the Intel 8080, so it's "binary compatible" with the 8080. (This means if you were to have a program written in binary for the 8080, it would run exactly the same on a Z80) Programming on the Zilog Z80 is similar to programming in basic 8-bit x86, (Not full x86, remember, it's binary compatible with the 8080, not chips added afterwards that had more commands. If you know x86, the 8080 and Z80 syntax will be familiar to you.) just with different mnemonics and some added features like the Index registers. So the Z80 is an option if you're good at hardware and aren't afraid of reading a few datasheets. (The Z80 data sheet is very comprehensive and not terribly long.)

If you're not comfortable using the Z80 though, I would suggest the Intel Quark D2000 development board. It's supposedly arduino-like, and will run full 32 bit x86 assembly for you. The Quark will run [Zephyr](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-the-zephyr-real-time-operating-system-rtos-with-the-intel-quark), which is a Linux [Real Time Operating System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) that should simplify running code on the Quark by quite a bit.

Comment: 8080 is not x86.  8080 is not *binary* compatible with 8086, not even close.  [The start of x86: Intel 8080 vs Intel 8086?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6500) on retrocomputing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, thank you for pointing this out. It's just I've programmed in x86 and noted that it's very similar to the 8080 syntax, just with way more commands. I edited my answer to reflect this, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Would you perhaps have a write-up or some links related to assembly programming on the intel quark d2000? I have a few boards and no inclination to do anything but x86 assembly on them :-)

Comment: @TraianoWelcome I'm not sure, I'm sorry I wish I could be more of a help. I can try to help with the general process though, first step is to find out how to load a program onto the Quark. This will (hopefully) be trivial to do. The next step is to find out what architecture its processor uses and search how to program THAT instead of the Quark, since searching how to write assembly for the quark will yield very little results (I tried already) and it's really not what you're looking for anyway. After that, just find an assembler for the architecture you need and find out how (1 of 2)

Comment: @TraianoWelcome to send the assembly language program over to the Quark and you're good to go. A lot of the time sending an assembly program is very similar or exactly the same as sending, say, a C++ program over for a lot of microcontroller boards. I'm not positive if the Quark is like this but I would assume so. There's a microcontroller tag here on stack overflow and if you have any more questions I'd recommend you go and ask there, much smarter people than me will be able to give you more specific help. :-)  (2 of 2)

Comment: Thanks @Shades. I found out that Quark can run Zephyr Linux. If I can get nasm installed in Zephyr, then it's simply a matter of  build, link and execute within a shell.